# How to open Android Turn-based Multiplayer app directly when user taps a notification?

Tags: android, google-play-services, multiplayer, google-play-games

I am developing a Turn-based Multiplayer game based on Google Play Game Services.

If a player is participating in a match, but my app is not running, Google Play Game Services will show a notification whenever another player takes a turn in the match. Here is my problem: If the player taps the notification, Google Play Game Services will not open my app - it will open a default match UI provided by Google Game Play services. I would like my app to open directly.

Is there a way to achieve that? Reading through the documentation (https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/turnbasedMultiplayer) does not give me any clues.

Comment: No unfortunately not. Will keep looking though, as the default match UI also prevents players from reviewing invitation details before accepting invitations. For example, if the game is a match on words and supports many languages, an English speaking player might accept an invitation for a match on words just to find out that the match is on French words.

Comment: thanks @tron. I noticed we also have the same issue of our saved games being removed after making updates to the game. Hopefully that will be resolved too

Comment: I also noticed @user2456977. I wonder how many apps actually uses the Turn Based Multiplayer api, as these issues do not seem to have generated much attention.

Comment: I opened a change request: https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples/issues/160

Answer (score -1):

I guess it launches the game, but you handle the invitation in your game to show the default UI selection.

Comment: No, my game is not launced at all. Thats the problem.